# spark update a column with other dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark

how to write this code in spark Scala and spark + sql ?

```
  update a                      
    set                     
      a.value='1',                      
      a.name=b.old-name                      
    from tbl1 a , tbl2 b                   
    where a.f=b.f
```

Comment: You can update in spark, only if you are using selective file formats like databricks delta or apache hudi. Which file format you using ?

Comment: in spark (or scala), you dont update your data, transform it

Answer (score 0):

Create a TEMP Table using below

**`df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl1")`**
**`df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl2")`**

use **spark-sql** to fire the any SQL query

```
df  = spark.sql("update a set a.value='1', a.name=b.old-name from tbl1 a , tbl2 b where a.f=b.f")
```

Comment: ahhh.. sorry for that - we can use delta table or a PL/SQL function which can be triggered from spark . hope this helps

Comment: yeah that can possible but my requirement is if i have to write only using spark how can i achieve this.

Comment: where you want to update ? in a relational  DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need create a new dataframe with updated data:

```
   val joinDf=spark.sql("select a.<rest-fields>, '1' as 'value', b.old-name as 'name' from a inner join b on a.f=b.f")
```

If you are not using delta table you need to replace the table:

```
joinDf.write.format("csv").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("a")
```